# Blender 2.8 - default tab is empty

Tags: modeling

i recently started using blender 2.8 (was previously using 2.79), and out of the sudden my default tab goes empty. i can't find my objects **anywhere**. however, if i go any other tab - animation, uv editing... - it's all there! i've already tried deleting the Blender Foundation folder, but had no luck. anyone knows what i did wrong and how i can fix this? thanks!

[image]

Comment: Does pressing `home` with the cursor over the 3D view do anything?

Comment: YES, thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the view has gotten lost in space somehow. You can try pressing <kbd>Home</kbd> to zoom the view to the currently visible objects (where "visible" means not hidden or in a hidden collection), or you could use <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> to select everything and then zoom the view on the selection.